# MVC4 StyleBundle: Can you add a cache-busting query string in Debug mode?

Tags: caching, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I've got an MVC application and I'm using the `StyleBundle` class for rendering out CSS files like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include("~/Content/*.css"));
```

The problem I have is that in `Debug` mode, the CSS urls are rendered out individually, and I have a web proxy that aggressively caches these urls. In `Release` mode, I know a query string is added to the final url to invalidate any caches for each release.

Is it possible to configure `StyleBundle` to add a random querystring in `Debug` mode as well to produce the following output to get around the caching issue?

```
<link href="/stylesheet.css?random=some_random_string" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can create a custom IBundleTransform class to do this. Here's an example that will append a v=[filehash] parameter using a hash of the file contents.

```
public class FileHashVersionBundleTransform: IBundleTransform
{
    public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
    {
        foreach(var file in response.Files)
        {
            using(FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(file.IncludedVirtualPath)))
            {
                //get hash of file contents
                byte[] fileHash = new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(fs);

                //encode file hash as a query string param
                string version = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(fileHash);
                file.IncludedVirtualPath = string.Concat(file.IncludedVirtualPath, "?v=", version);
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

You can then register the class by adding it to the Transforms collection of your bundles.

```
new StyleBundle("...").Transforms.Add(new FileHashVersionBundleTransform());
```

Now the version number will only change if the file contents change.

Comment: Why not just use the file LastWrite date. Then you're not having to do all that disk read and CPU for SHA256. And if you insist on hashing, MD5 is enough - you're not after security, you're after a unique hash(good enough) with low cpu cycles.

Comment: Nope that won't work, your example doesn't work for me - response.Files is an Enumarable of FileInfo objects. (Web.Optimization Version=1.0.0.0). Looks like you need to use Version 1.1+

Comment: Thanks @bingles, for versioning I modified the code slightly, so that I use the main DLL assembly version, which gets auto-incremented after each auto-deployment.

Comment: Do you have to create a new FileHashVersionBundleTransform for each bundle or can you reuse one?

Comment: @Marie As far as I know, you should be able to reuse a single instance.

Comment: anyone know if this proposed solution will affect googles pagespeed metrics?

Comment: I'm not familiar with google page speed, but the general effect here is that any time a resource is modified, the url changes which invalidates the browser's cache (if it was cached). So probably depends on if google page speed is caching resources or not.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about google page speed metrics since this fix is supposed to apply to Debug mode only.

Answer (score 59):

You just need a unique string.  It doesn't have to be Hash.  We use the LastModified date of the file and get the Ticks from there.  Opening and reading the file is expensive as @Todd noted.  Ticks is enough to output a unique number that changes when the file is changed.

```
internal static class BundleExtensions
{
    public static Bundle WithLastModifiedToken(this Bundle sb)
    {
        sb.Transforms.Add(new LastModifiedBundleTransform());
        return sb;
    }
    public class LastModifiedBundleTransform : IBundleTransform
    {
        public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
        {
            foreach (var file in response.Files)
            {
                var lastWrite = File.GetLastWriteTime(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(file.IncludedVirtualPath)).Ticks.ToString();
                file.IncludedVirtualPath = string.Concat(file.IncludedVirtualPath, "?v=", lastWrite);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and how to use it:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css")
    .Include("~/Content/*.css")
    .WithLastModifiedToken());
```

and this is what MVC writes:

```
<link href="bundles/css/site.css?v=635983900813469054" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

works fine with Script bundles too.

Comment: This is great! And can easily be adapted to use a software version number instead of a date.  Thanks!

Comment: So simple.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @H Dog not working for me the cshtml file not resolving bundles

Answer (score 16):

This library can add the cache-busting hash to your bundle files in debug mode, as well as a few other cache-busting things: https://github.com/kemmis/System.Web.Optimization.HashCache

#### You can apply HashCache to all bundles in a BundlesCollection

Execute the ApplyHashCache() extension method on the BundlesCollection Instance 
**after all bundles have been added to the collection**.

```
BundleTable.Bundles.ApplyHashCache();
```

#### Or you can apply HashCache to a single Bundle

Create an instance of the HashCacheTransform and add it to the bundle instance you want 
to apply HashCache to.

```
var myBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundle_virtual_path").Include("~/scripts/jsfile.js");
myBundle.Transforms.Add(new HashCacheTransform());
```

Comment: I tried this but it required updating our version of WebGrease from 1.1.0 to 1.5.2, which introduced another bug, so I rolled it back. The initial revision of this package (Version 1.0.0) would not have required us to update WebGrease, however instead of installing that version I decided to go with the accepted answer from @bingles as it given us complete control.

Comment: Except now I see that the accepted answer also requires WebGrease 1.5.2.

Answer (score 9):

I've had the same problem but with cached versions in client browsers after an upgrade. My solution is to wrap the call to `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` in my own renderer that appends our version number in the query string like this:

```
    public static IHtmlString RenderCacheSafe(string path)
    {
        var html = Styles.Render(path);
        var version = VersionHelper.GetVersion();
        var stringContent = html.ToString();

        // The version should be inserted just before the closing quotation mark of the href attribute.
        var versionedHtml = stringContent.Replace("\" rel=", string.Format("?v={0}\" rel=", version));
        return new HtmlString(versionedHtml);
    }
```

And then in the view I do like this:

```
@RenderHelpers.RenderCacheSafe("~/Content/css")
```

Comment: This is a great workaround if you're stuck on Web.Optimization Version 1.0.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Not currently but this is slated to be added soon (right now scheduled for the 1.1 stable release, you can track this issue here: [Codeplex](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/40)

Answer (score 1):

Note this is written for Scripts but also works for Styles (just change those key words)

Building on @Johan's answer:

```
public static IHtmlString RenderBundle(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string path)
{
    var context = new BundleContext(htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext, BundleTable.Bundles, string.Empty);
    var bundle = System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor(path);
    var html = System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render(path).ToString();
    foreach (var item in bundle.EnumerateFiles(context))
    {
        if (!html.Contains(item.Name))
            continue;

        html = html.Replace(item.Name, item.Name + "?" + item.LastWriteTimeUtc.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
    }

    return new HtmlString(html);
}

public static IHtmlString RenderStylesBundle(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string path)
{
    var context = new BundleContext(htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext, BundleTable.Bundles, string.Empty);
    var bundle = System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor(path);
    var html = System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render(path).ToString();
    foreach (var item in bundle.EnumerateFiles(context))
    {
        if (!html.Contains(item.Name))
            continue;

        html = html.Replace(item.Name, item.Name + "?" + item.LastWriteTimeUtc.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
    }

    return new HtmlString(html);
}
```

Usage:

```
@Html.RenderBundle("...")
@Html.RenderStylesBundle("...")
```

Replacing

```
@Scripts.Render("...")
@Styles.Render("...")
```

Benefits:

- Works for v1.0.0.0 of System.Web.Optimizations
- Works on multiple files in the bundle
- Gets the file modification date, rather than hashing, of each file, rather than a group

Also, when you need to quickly workaround Bundler:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ResolveUrl(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string url)
{
    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
    var resolvedUrl = urlHelper.Content(url);

    if (resolvedUrl.ToLower().EndsWith(".js") || resolvedUrl.ToLower().EndsWith(".css"))
    {
        var localPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(resolvedUrl);
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(localPath);
        resolvedUrl += "?" + fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(resolvedUrl);
}
```

Usage:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Html.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")"></script>
```

Replacing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")"></script>
```

(Also replaces many other alternative lookups)