# How do I add a date to the end of a CSS sheet call when using Bundle Collections?

Tags: c#, css, browser-cache

I'm trying to keep CSS from caching. To do so I'm trying to time stamp my CSS. In including CSS the basic way would look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?Thursday 24th of April 2008 04:45:21 PM" />
```

But on my project I am using `BundleConfig` to handle all CSS and JavaScript includes:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/myStyles").Include(
            "~/Content/Styles/style1.css",
            "~/Content/Styles/style2.css",
            "~/Content/Styles/style3.css"));
    }
}
```

I read about `Bundle.CacheLookup` and `Bundle.UpdateCache`, but I am confused. I don't think they are what I'm looking for.

What do I do with my `BundleCollection` to get it to include the question mark and a date time value when it produces the basic CSS call for the browser?

Comment: bundles should automatically add a timestamp.  are you saying you want to customize the format of that timestamp?

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005481/mvc4-stylebundle-can-you-add-a-cache-busting-query-string-in-debug-mode

Comment: @Xiaoy312 That is perfect! Thank you!