# MVC Bundle collection browser cache not cleared for all client browser's after code changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, bundle

We are using asp.net-mvc-5 with Bundling and minification that having cache problem: (browser cached old bundle files after code upgrade in server and every client needs to delete browser cache by manual). Without setting `HttpCacheability.NoCache` because we need data cache to be alive. Only
request to clear the bundle cache.

[How to force BundleCollection to flush cached script bundles in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317391/how-to-force-bundlecollection-to-flush-cached-script-bundles-in-mvc4)

[MVC4 StyleBundle: Can you add a cache-busting query string in Debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005481/mvc4-stylebundle-can-you-add-a-cache-busting-query-string-in-debug-mode)

I have already tried these two solution but its not working for my scenario.
Kindly provide a solution to clear client browser caches after each bundle file upgrade or provide functionality to retrieve latest bundles.

Comment: Once you used to bundle all files stored in cache if you change any file it's not you reflated need to hard reload or clear cache.

Comment: Example `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")` you have maybe use like this so please try to add some configuration like `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap?x=1")` very first if you have changed inside the file then just changes query string value like this `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap?x=2")`

Comment: It doesn't work for my scenario because I'm using bundle in my master application and that service are pointed out by several sub application. so I can't able to make changes in sub application like this `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap?x=1")`